# Kinetic JS - Rotate image based on mouse angle

Tags: image, rotation, mouseevent, kineticjs

I am trying to rotate an image on its center using the angle of the mouse on the stage.  It rotates using:

```
  dlayerA1.rotate(degree);
```

but it flys all over and does not rotate on its center!!  Complete project http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/eHJgJ/.
Would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is that you are not rotating an image at all, you are rotating the layer, also your layer is centered at 0,0 , so your image rotates around that. If you initially set up your image at 0,0 you will see that it rotates much nicer.

Try these simple test changes:

```
    // reposition the layer
    dlayerA1 = new Kinetic.Layer({x: 50,y: 50});

    //move the image
    dImage1 = new Kinetic.Image({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                image: dicom1,
                width: 150,
                height: 150
    });

    //inside handleMouseMove(), switch it to dImage1 being rotated <---- this is the fix that answers your original question
    dImage1.rotate(degree);
```